# Multiple regression with class probabilities

Tags: regression

I'm given a list of class probabilities $(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_c)$ (which sum to 1) for each sample. Now, I'd like to replicate this with a model (supervised learning).
How can I approach this?

I could use a separate regression model for each of $p_1, \dots, p_{c-1}$. But the probabilities might exceed 1 and also the models are independent, which both loses information.

I could use a classification method where I try to predict probabilities for classes. But then the input for each sample is a single class (the largest class probability). Here I'm losing the details of the given probabilities.

The goal is actually to closely match the given class probabilities.
Anything more direct and appropriate?

Comment: can you be more specific? What are the features that according to them your samples are classified?

Comment: The features are real numbers which I will create by feature engineering.

Answer (score 1):

ok there is a very simple way of doing this, although not neccesary the best way of doing it. It all depends on the problem you trying to solve. If we're allowed to assume that the features are uncorrelated or independent from each other. The posterior of being in a class $c$ is equal to:

\begin{equation}
p(c | F_1, F_2, ..., F_n) = p(c) \times \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} p(F_i|c)}
{\sum_{c'} \prod_{k=1}^n p(F_k| c')} 
\end{equation}

This model is what it's referred to as [Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) method, where features are assumed to be independent from each other. If your information gives no preference toward any classes, then just set the prior probability $p(c)$ to a simple uniform probability. 
To learn this model, there are many packages, such as http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~jc/teaching/arin/R_practical/.